# Text format in a row in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, text

after displaying with success text in my tablview rows, i didn't manage to put a Label and some extra text in the rows. As a text in normal font and extra text in tinnier font.
When i execute this code i have my device displaying 18 Rows with the "creation_date" something in my database. But i want to display the "creation_date" and the "name" of each row. If i copy and paste the cell.textLabel line and change "creation_date" with "name", i get a SIGABRT :8 If someone can help me please ? here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSString *LBLS = @"go";
NSString *LBLR =@"smogogo";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 50);
UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
lbl1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
[lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
[lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
LBLS = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"module"];
if ([LBLS isEqualToString:dataType]){
lbl1.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"creation_date"];
LBLS = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"module"];
if ([LBLS isEqualToString:dataType])
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];}

CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);
UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
lbl2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
[lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
[lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
lbl2.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"name"];
if ([LBLS isEqualToString:dataType]){
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
    [lbl2 release];}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: The `UITableViewCell initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` method has been deprecated since iOS 3.0. Use the proper method to set the cell's style.

Comment: Okay i will find a way and re-edit, but my concern is in the cell.textLabel line.

Comment: What is your concern? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Thank you to not giving up ^^. When i execute this code i have my device displaying 18 Rows with the creation_date that are in my database. But i want to display the creation_date and the name of each row. If i copy and paste the cell.textLabel line and change creation_date with name, i get a SIGABRT :8.

Comment: Update your question with the code that is giving you problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a custom UITableViewCell:

LaFiltersTableCell.h

```
@interface LAFiltersTableCell : UITableViewCell {
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *filterNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectedOptionsLabel;
```

LaFiltersTableCell.m

```
 + (LAFiltersTableCell *)getNewLAFiltersTableCell {
     NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LAFiltersTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
     for (NSObject *obj in xib) {
         if ([obj isKindOfClass:[LAFiltersTableCell class]]) {
             return (LAFiltersTableCell *)obj;
         }
     }
     return nil;
```

}

Make a nib file for your custom Cell and keep in mind the following : the class of the nib view must be LAFiltersTableCell, link the IBOutlets that you want to set, set the cell identifier that you will use in the tableview's data source.

The tableview's datasource:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     LAFiltersTableCell *filterCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LAFiltersTableCell"];
     if (filterCell == nil) {
         filterCell = [LAFiltersTableCell getNewLAFiltersTableCell];
     }
     filterCell.filterNameLabel = @"Test";
     filterCell.selectedOptionsLabel = @"Some other Test";
    return filterCell
 }
```

Comment: I will dive into you answer and tell if i managed to achieve this. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No problem at all. It's very useful to know how to handle custom table cells. This will provide a good practice example; please keep me on the feedback

Comment: Sorry if i take time to feedback, but i'am style fighting with it :3.

Comment: I get 2 warnings and a SIGABRT :8. I must do something wrong :3.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the warnings and the crash ?

Comment: at the "filterCell.filterNameLabel" & "filterCell.selectedOptionsLabel" get the warning and SIGABRT signal :§. But i managed to print the two strings in one cell, it works ^^!. Do you want me to edit the post and show you how i tinker it ? Thanks for your help and care, really appreciated it a lot :D!

Comment: Sure,:D usually SIGABRT signal is when you forget to add a xib file to  your project. Did you create LAFiltersTableCell.xib ?

Comment: (i have edited the post) haaa :'( i knew i was doing something wrong :§. Anyway, even if it's working, i'm going to do it your way ^^, it's way more clear, clean, and elegant :D!.

Comment: :D thanks, let me point out a small problem 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

The problem here is that, you are dequeue-ing a cell  (means that you are reusing an already created cell) and right after that you are alloc init-ing another one; The problem here is that, if you have a data source with 200 objects you will have 200 cells alloced,  which is something that we don't want.

Comment: If you look at my cellForRowAtIndex path you can see that: I'm trying to reuse a cell, and if the cell I get is nil, then and only then i'm getting a new one otherwise I'm reusing the old cells. Basicly the max number of cells alloced in your case should be how many cells are in your screen. When a cell dissapears from the screen, it is going into a prepare for reuse state, so you can reuse the allocated instance, only change the values of the labels/views inside it

Comment: So it is why i see the allocated Ram going up like a rocket when i start the app ^^!  Outstanding help :D !

Comment: No problem at all :D Also I recommend not alloc-ing stuff in cellForRowAtIndexPath, stuff like UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];  Imagine that you are making a clothing catalog with Price, Special Price, Brand, Product Name and Image. If you are spending time to alloc stuff at every scroll, maybe on an iPod 4 the performance would not be best :D.  Of course for 2 extra labels, the difference is small, but if you're adding an image to that, that has a loading spinner you will see the app move slow

Comment: You sir really think about everything :D. I will do as you say, can't pass on so much good advices, gold nuggets for a beginner like me :D !